# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')), Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web, python-requests

I made a telegram bot and deployed it on Render.
All works fine for like 3 hours then the bot gets down and throws this error:

```
`raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`
```

Worth mentioning that the server keeps being Live despite the error, but the bot gets totally out of service.

And when re-deploying it, it works fine for another 3 hours and then bot dies but server keeps Live.

I tried adding this code:

```
time.sleep(0.45)
r = requests.get(get_url(name), headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
soup = bs(r.content, features='html.parser')
```

But did not help that much.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I just needed to use
`bot.infinity_polling()`
instead of `bot.polling()`